# simple text list to link and class using php loop

Tags: php, explode

I want to convert a text and comma separated text to link and class, Like:

```
facebook.com,facebook
twitter.com,twitter
youtube.com,youtube
```

text before comma will be link and text after comma will be link class attribute, like

```
$link = text before comma
$class= text after comma
<a href="$link" class="$class">$class</a>
```

and get all list using loop.
please don't put half code, treat me as beginner and help me,
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to pull from a database. I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say you're just using the basic `mysql_*` functions.

```
$sql = "SELECT columnName from `tableName`";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, $row['columnName']) AS $line){
    // PHP_EOL is a line ending for that system, if you are positive that the column
    // is separated by \n, or \r\n then replace that instead of PHP_EOL
    list($link, $lcass) = explode(',', $line);

    echo '<a href="'.$link.'" class="'.$class.'">'.$class.'</a><br />';
}
```

I think $lcass will be $class

Comment: He said in a comment to my answer that it's all coming off in value, not per-row.

Comment: Updated post. Assuming each link,class is separated by a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$file = fopen('csv_file.csv', 'r');
$data = array();
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
   $data[] = array('link' => $line[0], 'class' => $line[1]);
}
fclose($file);

foreach ($data as $line) {
   $link = $line['link'];
   $class= $line['class'];
   echo "<a href='$link' class='$class'>$class</a>
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay. can you please tell me what to do if i am getting list of text from database instead a file, var i am using to get list from database is `$sociallinks`. thanks again for help

Comment: Is it coming of the database one line at a time?

Comment: In multiple rows, is what I'm getting at. Do you have an array of one-line data?

Comment: all text list are saved in one row, sorry I am not an expert programmer

Comment: How are you delimiting between records? Is there a semi-colon between the individual records?

Comment: please wait I will check it first

Comment: record saved in database is `facebook.com\\mylink,facebo‌​ok\r\ntwitter.com\\mylink,twitter`, i made a var called $socialLinkList which retrieve this data from database